# How to store a video file in exe file in c# and play it

Tags: c#, winforms, video, windows-media-player

I am working with winForms in c#. I want to access video file from resources without using any dialog box for load or select. That means I want directly store video file in EXE file.

```
 private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {  
      axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL=(videoForms.Properties.Resources.Airtel.wmv).ToString();
      axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();  
 }
```

I get warning while I execute this code. the warning is " byte[] that does not matches the file format" please help me to run this code.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you store it in the same directory as your exe?

Comment: I don't know what axWindowsMediaPlayer1 is but `(videoForms.Properties.Resources.Airtel.wmv).ToString();` is not a URL.

Comment: yes Mihai Caracostea, while I store it on the same directory, it has been working by giving that address. But if I store it on Resources it gives that type of warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps:**

1. Add your file as a resource.
2. Add Windows Media Player to your toolbox and then put it on Form.
3. Write this code to play your embedded video

**Code:**

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file=System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "YourFileName.wmv");
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(file))
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(file, Properties.Resources.YourFileName);

    this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = file;
    this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**More information:**

- [Using the Windows Media Player Control in a .NET Framework Solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/wmp/using-the-windows-media-player-control-in-a--net-framework-solution?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [Object Model Reference for Visual Basic .NET and C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/wmp/object-model-reference-for-visual-basic--net-and-c?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: Thank you so much Reza Aghaei