# c#/WinForms - Take file from resources and place it in directory on C: drive

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file, directory

I'm sure this has been done before and is probably quite simple to achieve but I can't seem to find anything on the internet when I've searched.
I'm looking for a way to pickup/copy a file from my applications resources and place it into a folder on my the C: drive.
 Can this be done? Or should I read in the contents of the file and then create a new one in the desired directory?
Any pointers/advice would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: ive certainly seen it done with resource strings, and images...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32287201/3110834

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the contents of the embedded file and write them out to your desired location as follows:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\Foo.txt", FileMode.Create))
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    var data = Stuff.Foo;
    sw.Write(data);
}
```

I did this for a text file embedded in `Stuff.resx` in my project. There's a `Write` overload for various types so you can use what you need. For instance, an image will come back as a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by using `File.WriteAllBytes()`

Example:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\MyApp\\TextExample.json", MyApp.Properties.Resources.TextExample);
```