# MediaPlayer open file from Resources

Tags: c#, winforms, uri, media-player

```cs
public battle(GameStateManager gsm,Image back)
    MediaPlayer myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    myPlayer.Open(new System.Uri("Resources\\sound\\music\\combat\\battle.wav"));    
    myPlayer.Play();
}
```

> url not found

Comment: Specify the full path. Where is `Resources` located?

Comment: Are you looking for [playing media which is stored in resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32287201/3110834) of a .Net Application?

Comment: You need to use absolute path, rather than relative path.